# How to overload subindex operator to behave differently in getting item and setting item?

Tags: c++

Suppose that I have this silly class

```
class C {
    char _data[8];
public :
    char getItem(const int index) const {return _data[index-1];}
    void setItem(const int index){_data[index+1] = 1;}
};
```

And as it shows that, this class supports two different behavior.

1. When I 'get' the nth item ,it will return _data[n-1]
2. But when I 'set' the nth item, it will set _data[n+1]

The problem is, can I overload operator[] to support this two behavior above?

Comment: Surely. Create a proxy class and have `operator[]` return an instance of that class.

Answer (score 2):

You can have `operator[]` return a proxy class that overloads `operator=` to set the value and conversion to `char` to get the value:

```
#include <iostream>

class C {
public:
    char _data[8];

    class Proxy {
        friend class C;
        C* instance;
        int index;
        Proxy(C* p, int i) : instance(p), index(i) {}
    public:
        Proxy& operator=(char c)
        {
            instance->_data[index+1] = c;
            return *this;
        }
        operator char()
        {
            return instance->_data[index-1];
        }
    };

public :
    C() = default;
    Proxy operator[](int index) { return Proxy(this, index); }
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c[0] = 42;
    std::cout << int(c[2]);
}
```

Output is `42`.

This is indeed a bit silly. You'll probalby want to make `Proxy` uncopyable, too. Also, const correcntess becomes trickier, as there's a layer of indirection between a `const` object `C` and the class that actually changes it.

Comment: A second ConstProxy will fix const correctness issues

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak a bit the operator overloadings to obtain something that might suit you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

class baseC {
protected:
    char _data[8];
    int index;
    public:

    void operator=(const int setValue) {
        if(setValue >= (unsigned)std::numeric_limits<char>::max()) {
            cout << "Unallowed value" << endl;
            return;
        }
        cout << "operator= with setValue " << setValue << " and index " << index << endl;
        _data[index+1] = setValue;
    }

    operator int(){
        cout << "operator int with index " << index << endl;
        return _data[index-1];
    }

    baseC() {} // Only instantiable via derived class
};

class C : public baseC {
public :
    char getItem(const int index) const {return _data[index-1];}
    void setItem(const int index){_data[index+1] = 1;}

    baseC& operator[](const int index) {
        cout << "operator[] with index " << index << endl;
        this->index = index;
        return static_cast<baseC&>(*this);
    }

};

int main() {
    C obj;

    obj[0] = 0x22;
    cout << (int)obj[2];

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/pQYJ5A

Of course the above comes with some restrictions and more strict type-checking